# Nightmare issue with Angular and WebApi2.2 JSON parse

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

That's what the problem is:

My WebAPI 2.2 (ASP NET) has a controller which returns from db context info about Clients. It looks like that:

```
public class ClientsController : ControllerBase
{ 
   [HttpGet("[action]")]
   public  IEnumerable<Client> GetClient()
   { 
      return _context.Client;
   }
}
```

Clients side app (written in angular) should recive the data and display it. As long as I hard code some data in controller it works fine, but when it is _context.Client, there is an errow thrown (below) in console.

Angular code:

```
  public clients: Client[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<Client[]>(baseUrl + 'api/Clients/GetClient').subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.clients = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

And the error is  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.l, message: Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/api/Clients/GetClient

I am being suspicious about this Client[] array, anyone knows something about similar problems?

Comment: seems you are not receiving valid json.

Comment: Yes I think that might be the issue, but what should I change?

Comment: It works well when I test.Do you use asp.net or asp.net core? Does the `_context.Client` have content?Could  you try to return with `Ok()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need declare your api like

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetClient")]
public  IEnumerable<Client> GetClient(){...}
```

But not sure about Web API 2.2, check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) (*)

(*)Sure you've already reade the docs, but be carefull, it's not the same Action that ActionName, and the things are changing so quickly (really it's a nigthmare)